# javascript closures and local variable 'remembering'

Tags: javascript, closures

Question is about JS closures. I have red the definitions and examples of it, and I believe I fairly understand the mechanism. So, the question is about specific thing I do not understand.
Please consider following two codes.
Code 1:

```
function a(){
let x = 5;
return function b(y){
    x=x+y;
    return x;
};
}

let c = a();
let d = c(3);
let e = c(4);
console.log(d);  // logs 8
console.log(e);  // logs 12
```

Code 2:

```
function a(){
let x = 5;
return function b(y){
    x=x+y;
    return x;
};
}

let d = a()(3);
let e = a()(4);
console.log(d);  //logs 8
console.log(e);  //logs 9
```

Question: In code 1 `x` changes its value and the new value is saved in a closure. In code 2 `x` changes its value and the new value is not saved. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the second example, you're calling `a` a second time, while in the first one `a` is only called once. Each time you call `a`, the value of `x` is initialised as 5. It is the inner function which is returned which creates the closure, and the value of `x` is remembered between invocations of that function. But each time you return a new function from `a`, it initially has access to an `x` which holds the value 5.

Comment: Isn`t it the same as calling it through `c` for the first time, and with the argument for the second time?

Comment: In the code 1,  when calling `e`, isnt it like calling `a()` through `c`, and then passing it argument `4`. Why is then `x` not initialised as `5`?

Comment: Forget the previous questions, I figured it out, based on your answer. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)